# How to fix "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Environment:**

Python 3.7

Windows 10 64bits

IDE Pycharm 2019

**Problem:**

The piece of code below used to work without issue. I had to move the folder of my Pycharm project and now I get this error message: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".

**The code:**

```
import os    
import psutil    

mypid = os.getpid()
print(f"PID of Program: {mypid}")
PROCNAME = "Program.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print(f"proc : {proc} - Type: {type(proc)}")
    print(f"proc.name : {proc.name} - Type: {type(proc.name)}")
    print(f"PROCNAME : {PROCNAME} - Type: {type(PROCNAME)}")
    print(f"proc.pid : {proc.pid} - Type: {type(proc.pid)}")
    print(f"mypid : {mypid} - Type: {type(mypid)}")
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME and proc.pid != mypid:  # < ====== Line 15 where is the error
        print(f"Program will kill this process : {proc}")
        proc.kill()
```

**The error output:**

```
PID of Program: 4176
proc : psutil.Process(pid=0, name='System Idle Process') - Type: <class 'psutil.Process'>
proc.name : System Idle Process - Type: <class 'str'>
PROCNAME : Program.exe - Type: <class 'str'>
proc.pid : 0 - Type: <class 'int'>
mypid : 4176 - Type: <class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/CFF Dropbox/Gauthier Buttez/cff/Python/PhoneBot_0002/test1.py", line 15, in <module>
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME and proc.pid != mypid:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**What I tried:**

I isolated this piece of code in a blank python document. I wanted to be sure the issue is not connected to other piece of code located somewhere else.
When I execute this isolated piece of code, I get same issue.

I watched here similar questions about "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", but all the answers are specific to the code of the question and it didn't help me to understand the problem.

What I am doing wrong. As you can see I print the value and the type of each variable and I am comparing string to string and int to int. What is the issue? I don't understand. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

```
proc.name()
```

`proc.name` is a string, not a method. Access it using `proc.name`, with no parentheses.

As a rule of thumb, whenever you are facing a `*** object is not callable` error you should look for a set of misplaced `(...)`.